# Sencha touch SDK command tools version3 commands on Mac not being recognised

Tags: macos, extjs

I am trying to run Sencha touch commands on my macbook pro but I am getting an error when
I run this command 'sencha' to test if the SDK command tools is installed properly.

the error message is this:   -bash: sencha: command not found

Can someone help me resolve the issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command Not Found
Upon running sencha, if there is an error message appears saying "sencha: command not found" on OS X / Linux or "'sencha' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." on Windows, follow these steps to troubleshoot:

Close all existing terminal / command prompt windows and re-open them.
Make sure that Sencha SDK Tools is properly installed:
The installation directory exists. By default, the installation path is /Applications/SenchaSDKTools-{version} on OS X, /opt/SenchaSDKTools-{version} on Linux, and C:\Program Files\SenchaSDKTools-{version}
The path to SDK Tools directory is prepended to your system's PATH environment variable. From the terminal, run echo $PATH (echo %PATH% on Windows). The SDK Tools directory should be displayed in part of the output. If this is not the case, add it to your PATH manually.
The environment variable SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_{version} is set, with the value being the absolute path to the installation directory mentioned above. For example: If the installed version is '2.0.0-beta2', a SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2 must be set. From the terminal, run echo $SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2 (echo %SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2% on Windows). If the output is empty, set the environment variable manually.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command